# Looking for Schmickler-Hirzebruch' monograph on elliptic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, hypergeometric-functions, elliptic-surfaces

I wonder if it is possible to find (and if yes, where?) an electronic copy of the following monograph:

**Author:** Schmickler-Hirzebruch, Ulrike

**Title:**  *Elliptische Flächen über $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ mit drei Ausnahmefasern und die hypergeometrische Differentialgleichung.*

Schriftenreihe des Mathematischen Instituts der Universität Münster, 2. Serie 33. Universität Münster, Mathematisches Institut, Münster, 1985. 170 pp.

(see MR0783064 (86i:32053)  or Zbl 0589.14011).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the journal that is now called the [Münster Journal of Mathematics.](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/mjm/index.html) Only recent volumes, from 2008, are online. The complete journal, including the volume 33 you are looking for, has actually been digitized by [Hathitrust](http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000639329), but for copyright reasons the access to it is restricted (search only). The only way to go seems to consult a library, here is a [list](http://www.worldcat.org/title/schriftenreihe-des-mathematischen-instituts-der-universitat-munster/oclc/6417840).